# Recurrence relation and big-O-notation

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Consider the following recurrence relation:
$$T(n)=c\cdot + 2\cdot T(n/2)$$

This is the recurrence relation for the Merge-Sort algorithm.
How can one deduce from this equation the time complexity of the algorithm which I know is: $$T(n) = O(n\cdot \log n)$$.

Comment: Do you know about Master Theorem ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I guess I should :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form This might help .

Comment: [This book](http://bmb.cu.edu.tr/caci/ftp/B%DDL453/Introduction_to_algorithms_3rd_edition.pdf) has a very good section on it.

Comment: Cool. Thank you, both of you.

Comment: you're very welcome. :)

Comment: Most welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "change of variable" $U(k)=2^{-k}T(2^k)$ yields the recursion
$$
U(k)=U(k-1)+\frac{c}{2^k},
$$
hence, for every $k$,
$$
U(k)=U(0)+c\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac1{2^i},
$$
in particular,
$$
U(0)\leqslant U(k)\leqslant U(0)+c\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^i}=U(0)+c,
$$
that is,
$$
2^k\cdot T(1)\leqslant T(2^k)\leqslant2^k\cdot(T(1)+c),
$$
which is usually translated as
$$
T(n)=\Theta(n).
$$
This analysis addresses the recursion as written in the question, namely,
$$
T(n)=c+2T(n/2).
$$
However, this is **not** the recursion describing the merge-sort algorithm, which reads
$$
T(n)=c\cdot n+2T(n/2).
$$
The same change of variable as above reads
$$
U(k)=U(k-1)+c,
$$
hence, for every $k$,
$$
U(k)=U(0)+c\cdot k,
$$
that is,
$$
T(2^k)=2^k\cdot T(1)+c\cdot k\cdot2^k=\Theta(k\cdot2^k),
$$
which is usually translated as
$$
T(n)=\Theta(n\cdot\log n).
$$